# How to replace a specific line in a file with a string variable using the line number bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Here is the contents of a target.txt file:

```
line1
line2
Environment=xLink=https://11111/route
line4
line5
```

I am trying to write a bash script that will find the number of the line containing 'https' and then replace this entire line with a new string variable obtained within the bash script, here is the bash script without the replacement line:

```
#!/bin/bash

x="12345"
route="/route"
x_route="${x}${route}"
x_init="Environment=xLink=https://"
new_line="${x_init}${x_route}"

echo "${new_line}"

to_replace_line_number=$(find target.txt -type f | xargs grep -n 'https' | cut -c1-2)

echo "${to_replace_line_number}"

targetfile=target.txt

echo "${targetfile}"
```

Invoking this script outputs the following as expected:

```
Environment=xLink=https://12345/route
3:
target.txt
```

Now, without the bash script, if I invoked:

```
sudo sed -i '3 c\Environment=xLink=https://12345/route' target.txt
```

The target.txt changes as desired to:

```
line1
line2
Environment=xLink=https://12345/route
line4
line5
```

But the goal is to automate, so I am trying to use sed command to do the job inside the bash script. So far I tried two methods, none of them worked.

Method 1:
I added the following line to the bash script:

```
sudo sed -i "${to_replace_line_number}s/.*/${new_line}/" ${targetfile}
```

When I ran the script, it didn't work and I got this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: : doesn't want any addresses
```

Method 2:
I added the following command to the bash script:

```
sudo sed -i "${to_replace_line_number} c\${new_line}" ${targetfile}
```

When I ran the script, it didn't work and I got this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: : doesn't want any addresses
```

What is that I am missing exactly? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: assuming `${to_replace_line_number}` == `3:`, your `sed` becomes: `sed -i "3: c\...`; this would seem to match with the error message about `char 2` == `:`; why jump through the hoops of finding a line number when `sed` is capable of finding, and replacing, the line containing `https` without the need for any line numbers?

Comment: Oh ya, I tried this and I can't get it to work. I am already struggling with getting sed to do a specific thing that is replace line number 3 with a string variable. I am not obviously ready or capable of invoking a single sed command within a bash script that will find the line and replace it, could you share your approach or a line of code or something?

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are taking out two characters when reading the line number.As a result, an extra ':' is popping up in the variable. Instead, take out only the one field and it should work fine.

Replace

```
to_replace_line_number=$(find target.txt -type f | xargs grep -n 'https' | cut -c1-2)
```

with

```
to_replace_line_number=$(find target.txt -type f | xargs grep -n 'https' | cut -c1)
```

Comment: this works as long as the matching line number is `< 10`; probably better to use `cut -d":" -f1` as this will give us the entire line number regardless of how many digits (1, 2, 5, ...)

Answer (score 2):

`\` is a special character, so when you use it in double quotes you have to escape it:

```
# Set example values and create a test file:
to_replace_line_number="3"
new_line="Environment=xLink=https://12345/route"
targetfile="test.txt"
printf 'line%d\n' {1..5} > "$targetfile"

# The actual command
sudo sed -i "${to_replace_line_number} c\\${new_line}" "${targetfile}"
```

This would make it equivalent to your manual invocation.

If you have wondered why the documentation for `c` appears to be weirdly formatted compared to `r` or `y`, it's because the linefeed after the `\` is intentional. This is the POSIX way of doing it:

```
sudo sed -i "${to_replace_line_number} c\\
${new_line}" "${targetfile}"
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple issues with the current code:

- `to_replace_line_number` == `3:` - **NOTICE** the colon (`:`); this is fed into the `sed` command like such: `sed -i "3: c\....` and is generating the error message stating an issue with the 2nd character, ie, the `:`
- as @thatotherguy has pointed out in his answer, the `c\` option requires an escape character and an embedded carriage return ... or ...

Minimal changes to OPs current code:

```
# parse the `grep -n` by having `cut` pull everthing before the (first) `:`

$ to_replace_line_number=$(find target.txt -type f | xargs grep -n 'https' | cut -d":" -f1)
$ echo "${to_replace_line_number}"
3

# modification to @thatotherguy's `sed/c` suggestion to allow all code to go on a single line:

$ sed -i -e "${to_replace_line_number} c\\" -e "${new_line}" ${targetfile}
$ cat "${targetfile}"
line1
line2
Environment=xLink=https://12345/route
line4
line5
```

---

Instead of spawning the sub-process calls to get the line number, there are several ways `sed` can be used to find and replace the desired line.

One `sed` idea:

```
sed -i "s|^.*https.*$|${new_line}|" ${targetfile}
```

Where:

- `|` - use pipe as `sed` delimiter since `${new_line}` contains forward slashes
- `^.*https.*$` - match any line that contains the string `https`
- `${new_line}` - replace the line with the contents of `${new_line}`

After running the above:

```
$ cat target.txt
line1
line2
Environment=xLink=https://12345/route
line4
line5
```

Comment: exactly, I forgot to adapt the original call to the example here but I am certainly happy with the two remarks/corrections